# Suppose that $f$ is continuous and that $g \circ f$ is differentiable. Must $f$ then be differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Suppose that $f$ is real function of a real variable defined on $(a,b)$ and that it is continuous on $(a,b)$. Suppose also that $g \circ f$ is differentiable on the set $f((a,b))$ and that $g$ is not constant function.

> Must $f$ then be differentiable on $(a,b)$?

Comment: Try $g$ constant.

Comment: @JulienGodawatta Can I edit the question to avoid such trivialities?

Comment: Try $g(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) =|x|$

Comment: Won't change the answer - take $f$ and $g$ injective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=|x|.$